# OpenShift access one WEB-app to another

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web-applications, openshift

I installed a tomcat wecontainer on my openshift server. I succesfuly deployed two WEB-app on tomcat.

The problem is that im trying to connect from one WEB-app to another. I'm using apache chemistry file share repository. And when im trying to connect to it from my own WEB-app redirectsNotSupported exception appears.

I think i need to find out the right address to connect.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: What address are you using for it now?

Comment: I tried it with the OPEN_SHIFT_DIY_IP which is 127.10.146.129. That's cause the  Redirects are not supported CmisException. From my browser i can easily access to the CMIS repository but from the server trough SSH i can't open it with wget command for example.

Comment: I managed to work with the normal url.